# Why the tar file is so big?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, tar

I created a tar file of a directory. The directory is a few MBs big.
The tar file has a size of more than 150 MBs!!!

I created the tar file with the command:

```
tar -cf <tar filename> <directory with the files to tar>
```

Why is the tar file so much biger than the normal directory or file?

Comment: Which command did you run? Which directory did you intend to archive?

Comment: Was the "`.tar`" file in the same directory? What does `tar tvf the_big_tar_file.tar` tell you?

Comment: I created the file with the command tar -cf <tar-filename> <filename>.
The command with -tvf showed me all directroys.

Comment: What did you actually type? `tar -cf <tar-filename> <filename>` is not a working command. The `tar tvf` told you what you actually put into the `.tar` file. Unless you can show us the exact command used to do that, we cannot determine what happened.

Comment: @waltinator why should this command doesnt Workshops?!? Thats the same syntax like in the ubuntu wiki. https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TAR

Comment: As pointed out above [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/653348/edit) your question and add the results of `tar -tvf the_big_tar_file.tar`